# How to match number of returned rows to number of arguments inside a SELECT-IN

Tags: sql, select, duplicate-data, ingres

I have the next query:

```
SELECT EMP.NAME FROM EMPLOYEES EMP WHERE EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID IN (1, 2, 1, 1)
ORDER BY EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

This last query returns 2 rows in an Ingres database (if EMPLOYEE_IDs 1 and 2 exist, that is). How would I have to modify this query in order to make it return 4 names, whether those IDs exist in the EMPLOYEES table or not (NULL or any other value), and including those EMPLOYEE_IDs that are repeated 2 or more times? I have seen many solutions for this kind of challenge but none of them apply to a SELECT IN clause.

What I ultimately want this query to help me with is in building a text file with multiple records, where an employee may appear in more than one record; can't afford to query each EMPLOYEE_ID because this query will have thousands of EMPLOYEE_IDs and database access is currently ephemeral, connection won't hold but a couple of minutes.

Hope I had explained myself well enough. -english is not my natural language.
Greetings.

Comment: **If** your are using this data from an application, have the application handle these concerns, and let the query just worry about retrieving the qualifying data

Answer (score 0):

It's better to apply the desired logic on client side, but if you want sql solution, you can use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT EMP.NAME FROM EMPLOYEES EMP WHERE  EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID  = 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT EMP.NAME FROM EMPLOYEES EMP WHERE  EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID  = 2
UNION ALL 
SELECT EMP.NAME FROM EMPLOYEES EMP WHERE  EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID  = 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT EMP.NAME FROM EMPLOYEES EMP WHERE  EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID  = 1
)a 
ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID
```

You can also do

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS EMPLOYEE_ID -- FROM DUAL - if you use Oracle
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1
)a
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES b ON (b.EMPLOYEE_ID = a.EMPLOYEE_ID)
ORDER BY a.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Comment: Based on the "whether those IDs exist in the EMPLOYEES table or not", I think the right answer is your second alternative, but using a `LEFT JOIN`. Depending on the SQL dialect, the `UNION ALL` may be better written using `VALUES`, but not all databases support it, and I don't know Ingres.

Answer (score 0):

I will do it like this:

Assuming you have an Employee table created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES ( EMPLOYEE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, name CHAR(10) NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES ( EMPLOYEE_ID, name ) VALUES ( 1, 'John' );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES ( EMPLOYEE_ID, name ) VALUES ( 2, 'Victoria' );
```

Implement the Employee ID list as a table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_LIST ( EMPLOYEE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_LIST ( EMPLOYEE_ID ) VALUES ( 1 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_LIST ( EMPLOYEE_ID ) VALUES ( 2 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_LIST ( EMPLOYEE_ID ) VALUES ( 1 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_LIST ( EMPLOYEE_ID ) VALUES ( 1 );
```

Then build the final list as a join:

```
SELECT b.EMPLOYEE_ID, b.name 
from EMPLOYEE_LIST a
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES b on (a.EMPLOYEE_ID = b.EMPLOYEE_ID)

+-------------+------------+
| employee_id |    name    |
+-------------+------------+
|           1 | John       |
|           1 | John       |
|           1 | John       |
|           2 | Victoria   |
+-------------+------------+
```

Note that the order is not preserved, if you need this than add a 'key' field in EMPLOYEE_LIST and add an `ORDER BY key` in the final SQL statement

PS: SELECT IN is not a good option - list (1, 2, 1, 1) internally gets compressed as (1, 2) i.e. any duplicates are eliminated since they are irrelevant.

For more details see [W3Schools.com SQL IN Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)